# Create image with DnD

Tags: java, swing

I'd like to create an own displayable image in Java - this is not the problem.
But this image should be draggable inside a JLabel (only within the JLabel).

First I plan to create a new class for this intention extended from class JComponent.
With this I can use createImage(ImageProducer producer) to create my image.
But how can I use this method?

Or is there another possibility to implement a draggable image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the JLabel and its image can move on mouseDragged?  You could do this with a JLayeredPane, and by adding a MouseListener to the JLabel or the layered pane.  For example: [dragging-a-jlabel-around-the-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893265/dragging-a-jlabel-around-the-screen/4894516#4894516)

Comment: Thanks, but I solved it in a different way... First I added a JLabel with an ImageIcon to a JPanel. Then I added a mousListener to the JLabel to get and set bounds of it while dragging. That's all I needed.