# Draggable rectangles in Java 2D

Tags: java, swing, uml, java-2d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to drag object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220971/how-to-drag-object)

I need to draw some UML components (classes, packages etc) using Java 2D and then be able to drag them around. Is there a way to do this? I mean, to make a shape "draggable"?

Comment: Are you looking for a [UML modeling tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools)or a basic [object-drawing example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513).

Comment: Yes, there is a way to drag objects around using Java 2D.  Could you share with us [what you've tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 4):

[`JHotDraw`](http://www.jhotdraw.org/) was designed as "a Java GUI framework for technical and structured Graphics." The linked [*JHotDraw Pattern Language: JHotDraw Domain Overview*](http://softarch.cis.strath.ac.uk/PLJHD/Patterns/JHDDomainOverview.html) illustrates how to customize drawing editors. The sample `org.jhotdraw.samples.draw.Main` is a reasonable starting point, and `JModeller` is a simple UML editor built using the framework.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to swing?

If not you might have look at [draw2d](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/draw2d/index.php) which is a java library that works on a [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) canvas. You can find some examples of draw2d [here](http://nyssen.blogspot.de/2010/12/draw2d-examples-hidden-treasure.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can only add MouseListener to a (J)Component. All Java2D stuff is painted on the component. If you manage all shapes in a List you can search for the correct shape under the mouse courser, move it and repaint the component.