# How to organize several ActionListeners

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JPopupMenu` with several `JMenuItem`s inside. Each `JMenuItem` has it's own `ActionListener`, but the code looks rather messy having several anonymous inner classes in a row. I've seen some people organize several `ActionListener`s like this:

```
public class Foo implements ActionListener {

    private JMenuItem item1, item2;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == item1) {
            ...
        } else if (e.getSource() == item2) {
            ...
        }
    }

}
```

While this looks neater, I don't like the idea of having it visible. Are there any better ways of organizing several `ActionListener`s?

Thanks

Comment: If you find the anonymous action listeners messy, why don't you make them non-anonymous?

Comment: You can use `Action`s as real classes instead of anonymous inner `ActionListener` classes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I organize my Actions in Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14736792/261156).

Answer (score 0):

This is basically [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)'s answer, but make the anonymous action listeners actual classes.

The short ones can remain in the menu class, and the larger ones can be put in their own class.  I usually put internal classes towards the bottom of the class.  Some people put them all at the top.

By making your action listeners actual classes, you can use a constructor to pass the JComponent instances to the action listener class.