# Displaying a tree data structure in Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-7, jtree

```
I intend to display a tree in Java GUI.
```

The nodes of the tree will depict the function names of the program which the user will enter during runtime and the edges of the tree will depict a function call. So if main calls func1, there will be 2 nodes in the tree (main and func1) and an edge from main to func1. It will differ according to the program which the user entered. This tree may not be a binary tree since a single function may call more than two functions and may be recursive.

I studied JTree and I felt I wont be getting the desired output in the desired design using it.

I even consider tools such as Prefuse but that will increase the size of my application.
Is there any other way of displaying the above?

Desired Output -
If the program is

```
void main()   //program begins here
{
   func1();
   func2();
}

void func1()
{
      x=0;
     if(x<5)
     {
        func1();
        x++;
     }
}

void func2()
{
      sum();
      diff();
      mul();
}

void sum()
{
      printf("2+5=7");
}
void diff()
{
      printf("2-5=-3");
}
void mul()
{
     printf("2*5=10");
}

Its output should be-

               main
              /   \
             /     \
      ----->func1  func2
      |-------|    /  \  \
                  /    \  \ 
                 sum   diff mul
```

I was not able to display the image. Its in
http://postimg.org/image/5uovbguz9/

Comment: *"Could someone please direct me."*   Form a question and add it as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16059275/edit).

Comment: We don't know your "desired design", your imaginations. Could you please provide some detail so one could come up with something that fits your needs?

Comment: @Powerslave I have edited the question to show the expected output. Since I does not have 10 reputation I was not able to upload the image. I have tried my best so that everyone can understand.Also I have attached the link to the image. Please check this out. I have been trying this since 4 days.

Comment: not supported in core swing, you might want to look into some 3rd party framework, f.i. JUNG

Comment: Or one of [these](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15702152/230513).