# Skeletal animation tool programming

Tags: java, image, swing, shapes

I'm looking into building a 2D skeletal animation tool where a person can add art assets and join to a bone created. What I'm having problem with is conceptualizing the beginning process of creating a single bone. I'm planning on using a canvas as the base for creating bones. The end result would be just to create two connecting bones, attach two images, then if I move on bone, the corresponding image will update its position/rotation accordingly.

What I'm looking for is how to achieve the basics. I understand that I first must create the shape of a bone (elongated tear drop) with an two anchors (a circle centered at at the base and point of the tear). I would like some conceptual input into achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although a complete solution is beyond the scope of StackOverflow, such an application will need to support moveable, connected nodes. The example cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11944233/230513) illustrates the basic drawing and event handling. More elaborate libraries are cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15702152/230513). Use `AffineTransform` to rotate a suitable connecting image, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3405799/230513).