# How to NOT extend Swing components?

Tags: java, swing, oop

I've seen a number of posters argue that Swing components should not be extended, and that functionality should instead be added via composition.  So say I want to reusably create a `JPanel` with absolute positioning (no layout manager) in which I can reposition components with the mouse:

```
public class MoveableComponentPanel 
{
    private final JPanel m_panel;

    public MoveableComponentPanel()
    {
        m_panel = new JPanel(null);
    }

    public void add(Component c)
    {
        m_panel.add(c);
        c.addMouseListener(m_mover);
        c.setSize(c.getPreferredSize());
    }   

    private final MouseListener m_mover = new MouseListener()
    {
        private int m_startX, m_startY;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                m_startX = e.getX();
                m_startY = e.getY();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1)
            {
                Component c = e.getComponent();
                Point p = c.getLocation();
                p.x += e.getX() - m_startX;
                p.y += e.getY() - m_startY;         
                c.setLocation(p);
                c.repaint();
            }
        }   

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
    };
}
```

Looks nice, but there's no way to add the panel to a container.  Further headaches if I want to allow a calling class to interact with the panel, e.g. change size, background color, register event listeners, etc.  Either I add a `getPanel()` accessor, which breaks encapsulation, or write pass-through methods for the `JPanel` methods/properties I want to expose (potentially many).  Is there some other strategy I'm missing here?  What is the accepted best practice?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with extending `JPanel` here...

Comment: *"I've seen a number of posters argue that Swing components should not be extended.."* As a person that often gives that advice, I'll point out that it is a 'general rule' rather than one that is chiselled into stone. There ***are*** valid cases where extending a component makes sense (e.g. custom painting).  *"..absolute positioning (no layout manager) in which I can reposition components with the mouse"* ..why? I hope this is not an attempt at trying to make a 'GUI designer', since the resulting GUIs will have all the problems usually inflicted upon GUIs made without layouts. ..

Comment: .. But if it actually turns out to be a good case for a D'n'D panel, I'd strongly suggest implementing a `DragAndDropLayout` because that will at least bring you to consider some of the things that could go wrong with it.

Comment: It's a UML class diagram viewer based on Reflection.

Comment: And thank you, I'll look into DragAndDropLayout

Comment: Extending `JPanel` gives you a UI delegate and lets you manage the [preferred size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/230513). See also `JHotDraw`, cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13997870/230513).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in which I can reposition components with the mouse:

Then you just add the `MouseListener/MouseMotionListener` to the components that you want to drag. There is no need to extend any component to add that functionality.

Check out the [Component Mover](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) class for examples of ways to do basic dragging of a component as well as a more complex dragging solution.

Comment: Wow, you're right.  I hadn't thought about it that way.  There really is no need for this functionality to be bound to any particular container type, and it's a lot more flexible if it isn't.  ComponentMover demonstrates that beautifully.  Thanks!