# how to know if mouse dragged left or right inside jpanel in java

Tags: java, jpanel, mousemotionevent

I have mouseMotionListener in my jpanel code.

But how can I know if the mouse dragged to left or right inside the jpanel?

Comment: You'ld need to put previous X and Y coordinates in variables/object, and then compare to the new values.

Comment: Have you tried reading [some documentation on it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mousemotionlistener.html)?? Or looked at some existing [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574065/java-mousedragged-and-moving-around-in-a-graphical-interface) (and there's a lot more of them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if (currentX > previousX) {
    // Right
} else {
    // Left
}
previousX = currentX;
```

in your listener.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the event callback: store the mouse-(x-)position, in the next callback calculate the difference to the previous position (and store the position again); depending on the sign(um) you can determine whether it was a left or right drag.