# Mouse Dragged out of Window

Tags: java, swing, mouse

This code is in my mouseDragged function and it drags the undecorated JFrame

```
if (mouse.y < 25 && !closePol.contains(mouse)){
    getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent().setLocation(new Point(e.getXOnScreen() - mouse.x, e.getYOnScreen() - mouse.y));
}
```

and I have code that sets `mouse = new Point()` whenever I move the mouse out of the JFrame.
It works fine but there is a bug. Whenever I start dragging with `mouse.y >= 25` and drag out the window, this [image: this] happens. The window moves the top left corner to the mouse.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: By the way, your code with its getParent().getParent()... etc looks to be very fragile. I'd look for a more robust way of getting my references.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried using getRootPane() but it didnt work. Then I gave a name to my main pane and used getParent.getName() and kept adding getParents until i got it.

Comment: How about that [minimal complete example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: And what is your desired appropriate behavior of this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5312702/230513), you need to offset your rendering point by the *difference* between the current mouse point and the previous mouse point. Give two instances of `Point`, `textPt` and `mousePt`,

```
this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        int dx = e.getX() - mousePt.x;
        int dy = e.getY() - mousePt.y;
        textPt.setLocation(textPt.x + dx, textPt.y + dy);
        mousePt = e.getPoint();
        repaint();
    }
});
```