# Java - mouseMoved() previous mouse position

Tags: java, mouseevent, mouse

In Java, I want to get the amount the mouse moved during the `mouseMoved()` event in the `MouseMotionListener`. I know the point given by the MouseEvent is where the mouse position is at that exact moment. Must I store a mouse position variable that is the previous mouse position? I would have to update it every time the mouse moved, or is there a better way?

Comment: The question is not clear properly. Can you give an example what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, you must store the previous position somewhere.

Comment: I want the position the mouse was at the exact moment before the mouse move event occurs

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312702/230513).

Comment: *"Must I store a mouse position...*" - Yes