# Java Swing Rectangel2D: how to select the one on the top

Tags: java, swing

easy question:

I draw more than one Rectangel2D （or other shapes） in one JPane with overlapping.
I want to select the one on the top by click the overlapping area and do something， e.g. change color or drag.

But I can't select the one which I want.

The order of the Shapes is not under control.

I find a method setComponentZOrder, but that is for component not for Rectangel2D.

I think this is a typical question, but I can't find the answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take the [tour] and go through the [help], then learn [ask] and once you've done that, come back with a proper [mcve] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 4):

The order that a Shape such as a Rectangle2D are drawn is determined by the order that they are held in whatever collection holds them as this collection is iterated through in your JComponent's (such as a JPanel's) painting method. Thus the last items in the collection, be it an array or ArrayList or LinkedList, is drawn on *top*.

So if you want to get the top Shape on mouse press or click, then the key will be to iterate through the same collection ***backwards***, getting the first Shape that `contains(Point p)` the mouse Point location. That's it.

For example, please look at my code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5601099/522444) which does just his in this method which is called from the MouseListener (actually MouseAdapater):

```
public Shape getShapeAtPoint(Point p) {
    Shape shapeAtPoint = null;
    for (int i = shapeList.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (shapeList.get(i).contains(p)) {
            return shapeList.get(i);
        }
    }
    return shapeAtPoint;
}
```

For example:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RandomShapes extends JPanel {
    private static final Stroke STROKE = new BasicStroke(4f);
    private static final int PREF_W = 800;
    private static final int PREF_H = 650;
    private static final int SHAPE_COUNT = 30;
    private static final int SHAPE_WIDTH = 100;
    private static final int SHAPE_HEIGHT = SHAPE_WIDTH;
    private List<Path2D> paths = new ArrayList<>();
    private Map<Path2D, Color> colorMap = new HashMap<>();
    private Random random = new Random();

    public RandomShapes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < SHAPE_COUNT; i++) {
            Shape shape = createRandomShape(i);
            Path2D path = new Path2D.Double(shape);
            paths.add(path);
            colorMap.put(path, createRandomColor());
        }
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private Path2D selectedPath = null;
        private Point p1;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }
            for (int i = paths.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                Path2D path = paths.get(i);
                if (path.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    selectedPath = path;
                    p1 = e.getPoint();
                    paths.remove(selectedPath);
                    paths.add(selectedPath);
                    repaint();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        private void movePath(MouseEvent e) {
            Point p2 = e.getPoint();
            int tx = p2.x - p1.x;
            int ty = p2.y - p1.y;
            p1 = p2;
            AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(tx, ty);
            selectedPath.transform(at);
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (selectedPath != null) {
                movePath(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (selectedPath != null) {
                movePath(e);
            }
            selectedPath = null;
        }
    }

    private Color createRandomColor() {
        float min = 0.2f;
        float h = random.nextFloat();
        float s = min * random.nextFloat() + (1f - min);
        float b = min * random.nextFloat() + (1f - min);
        return Color.getHSBColor(h, s, b);
    }

    private Shape createRandomShape(int i) {
        Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
        int x = random.nextInt(size.width - SHAPE_WIDTH);
        int y = random.nextInt(size.height - SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        switch (i % 3) {
        case 0:
            return new Ellipse2D.Double(x, y, SHAPE_WIDTH, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        case 1:
            return new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, SHAPE_WIDTH, SHAPE_HEIGHT);
        case 2:
            return new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, y, SHAPE_WIDTH, SHAPE_HEIGHT, 15, 15);
        default:
            break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setStroke(STROKE);
        for (Path2D path : paths) {
            g2.setColor(colorMap.get(path));
            g2.fill(path);
            g2.setColor(colorMap.get(path).darker());
            g2.draw(path);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RandomShapes");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new RandomShapes());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

---

Note that if you want to delete a shape on right mouse click (MouseEvent.BUTTON3), this edit to the MyMouse MouseAdapter class can make this happen (see comments in code):

```
private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    private Path2D selectedPath = null;
    private Point p1;

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        int button = e.getButton();
        
        // if the *middle* mouse button is pushed, ignore it
        if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON2) {
            return;
        } 
        
        // iterate through all the shapes, 
        // starting at the top of the list (last drawn shapes)
        for (int i = paths.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            
            Path2D path = paths.get(i); 
            if (path.contains(e.getPoint())) {
                
                // if the mouse presses on one of the shapes
                selectedPath = path;
                p1 = e.getPoint();
                
                // remove the shape from the collection
                paths.remove(selectedPath);
                if (button == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                    
                    // re-add it back in at the end of the collection 
                    // only if the left mouse button has been pressed
                    paths.add(selectedPath);
                }
                repaint();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    // ....
    
}
```