# Dragging a JLabel outside of a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jframe, jlabel

So I've been looking at this:  [dragging a jlabel around the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893265/dragging-a-jlabel-around-the-screen)

Is there a way to drag a JLabel (or a representation of one) outside of a JFrame?

For instance to drag a JLabel between JFrames, while actually "showing" the JLabel being dragged  (using http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html)

Comment: didn't you answer you own question?

Comment: How did I answer my own question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JWindow test:

```
//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893265/dragging-a-jlabel-around-the-screen
private final JWindow window = new JWindow();
@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
  if (dragLabel == null) {
      return;
  }
  int x = me.getPoint().x - dragLabelWidthDiv2;
  int y = me.getPoint().y - dragLabelHeightDiv2;
  //dragLabel.setLocation(x, y);
  window.add(dragLabel);
  window.pack();
  Point pt = new Point(x, y);
  Component c = (Component)me.getSource();
  SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(pt, c);
  window.setLocation(pt);
  window.setVisible(true);
  repaint();
}
@Override public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
  window.setVisible(false);
  //...
}
```

---

Below is not tested code:
(may take some massaging to work, but this is the gist of it)

```
@Override public int getSourceActions(JComponent src) {
  JLabel label = (JLabel)src;
  window.add(label);
  window.pack();
  window.setVisible(true);
  return MOVE;
}
//...
DragSource.getDefaultDragSource().addDragSourceMotionListener(new DragSourceMotionListener() {
  @Override public void dragMouseMoved(DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
    Point pt = dsde.getLocation();
    pt.translate(5, 5); // offset
    window.setLocation(pt);
  }
});
```